# Savings advice for a 16 year old with £20,000 - convicing my parents that investing this into a property is a bad idea

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, savings, investment-strategies

My younger brother runs a small yet lucrative business in his free time. He has accumulated around £20k in a very short time.

My mother wants him to put this money into buying a property, i.e: a mortgage, under someone else's name since he is most definitely not eligible for a mortgage (16 y/o, no job, still in school etc...). Her idea is to then rent the place out, using part of the rent to cover the mortgage and the rest can go into savings... somewhere.

I have advised her **against** this for the following reasons:

- <s>there are limitations as to when you can rent a property after buying a mortgage (I think). eg: can't rent it out until 6 months have passed - this will **cost** us (covering the mortgage fees until the property can be rented)</s>
- there will be gaps when there are no tennants - this will **cost** us.
- there are lots of costs in maintaining a property - this will **cost** us.
- if his business stops being lucrative it once again will put strain on the rest of the family's finances
- my brother will **learn nothing about financial responsibility** from the experience since everything will be done by our mother.
- difficult to track profit over time, due to points listed above.

I say it will cost *us* because my parents can barely afford the rent on our property as it is. As soon as they have to pay the mortgage fees out of their pocket, it will be my pocket too.

---

I have proposed that he invests his money in a low-cost, low-risk **index tracker**:

- easier to maintain
- yes, this is technically riskier than investing in property, but given our situation I think this is actually safer; way too many moving parts in my mother's proposal
- he is relatively technical/smart - he will enjoy **learning** about stocks and he will be able to track his savings himself.

Am I correct in my fears about the property idea?

I would not be against it if it was done when he is older, out of school, out of university, when there are less unknowns.

Comment: Are you **absolutely sure** brother is not eligible for a mortgage?  Have you **specifically asked at a bank** ?  Remember that of all the businesses that have ever existed on Earth, banks are the closest to staving dogs slavering after raw meat, in terms of wanting your money.  Banks will write a mortgage to anything, the only thing that restrains them is national rules.  You may find brother can easily get a mortgage.

Comment: @Fattie: that was true once; but not any more. The "stress tests" that UK banks apply when judging affordability of BTL mortgages (i.e. worst case interest rate rise vs expected rent) have become much, much tighter in the last year or two.

Comment: Buying property is actually much riskier than buying an index fund.  The ongoing costs are much higher - mortgage payments, taxes, insurance & upkeep vs an account maintenance fee that's a tiny percentage of the investment, and you have a bank or mortgage company that will foreclose if you don't keep up the payments, causing you to lose your entire investment.  Whereas with a stock fund, if the market drops - as it eventually will - you just have to wait until it goes up again  - which it eventually will.

Comment: To add to @jamesqf's excellent points, an index fund is also a lot more liquid and he can sell a fraction rather than his whole stake if he wants/needs to.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff - Assuming you won't get pinged from my comment on my now deleted answer: thanks for the link. I really shouldn't repeat internet wisdom without actually researching it myself... Seeing as you've debunked the whole premise of my answer, I've now deleted it.

Comment: @AndyT: sorry! :-(

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff - Ha, no worries. Better to make sure that any advice given is accurate than to worry about the 40 fake internet points I'd earnt!

Comment: @jamesqf "which it eventually will". There's no guarantee *whatsoever* that prices go up again after a drop in the market. Especially in the current state the US is in, with a huge mountain of debt, historically low interest rates and loads of pension money being thrown into the stock market. And even if markets recover, it takes years do to so. There are smarter ways to grow your money, saving yourself a couple of years of bad sleep while your stocks or fund is in the reds. (And even more if they don't go green anymore)

Comment: @RNobel: Perhaps you'd care to share some of those "smarter ways to grow your money"?  Because I can't think of any offhand that aren't high-risk, labor-intensive, or illegal - if not all three (drug dealing, for instance :-)).  Whereas market drops - I've weathered several - have never lost me a moment's sleep.

Comment: Past performance is no guarantee for the future. investing for the long term made sense from 1895 to 2000. since 2000 we've had three crashes already, the dotcom crash in 2000, real estate crash in 2007 and banking crash in 2008. All of them 'saved' by the central banks by printing money out of thin air. The uptrend after the recession is not caused by real growth, buy by magically injecting new money in the economy and lowering interest rates. This can go on for 1,2,3 times, maybe a 4th time. After that, it's over.

Comment: Interest rates cannot go any lower than zero (well, they can, but that wouldn't be exactly helpful) and printing money has it's boundaries. No one knows what's going to happen then, but it probably won't be pretty. So, while the stock market was a smart way to make money in the past, this will not be this way indefinitely. Humans tend to see patterns in historical behaviour, which is great. It can also be fatal; temporary behaviour (in this case, of the stock market) is mistaken for a law of nature ('the stock market always goes up'). Result: lots of money that can't be missed is lost.

Comment: Many books about this subject are written, along with more detailed explanation, charts and all. As to smarter ways to make money: investing in commodities, gold and silver ( through derivatives and a small part in physical form), in my experience, can be very profitable. Investing in real-estate can be profitable. Day-trading small caps can be very very profitable. But for all of those: proper education is necessary. Don't start without having done a proper course. I've lost a lot of money before I knew this. There's so much available to help us…lots of books, courses, blogs

Comment: @RNobel: The market goes up and down, and has done so as long as there have been markets.  Short of a zombie apocalypse, it's likely to go on doing so.  As for your suggestions:  Gold isn't an investment.  At best it's a hedge against inflation and/or unstable governments.  Passive real estate investing is (as I pointed out above) exposed many risks, including the same market crashes.  Active investing is work.  Likewise day-trading: even if you could consistently make a profit, it's work.

Comment: @RNobel: As for doing "a proper course" in any of those things, why?  I have a proper education in computer programming (among other things).  It's work I enjoy, and which is quite profitable.  (And could be more so if I cared to alter my lifestyle.)  I expect most people have similarly acquired skills in one or another field.  Why should any of us want to take on the extra work of one of those "investment" activities of yours, when we can just put our excess income into good mutual funds, and not think of them more than once a month, if that?

Comment: jamesqf, that's the whole problem with the stock market. People that don't know how to invest and don't want to know participate in it. Every trader knows that markets go up and down, yet all those unknowing 'investors' believe that markets always go up and trust their hard earned money to the people running mutual funds, making nice profits off of the fees of the funds, all the while knowing exactly what's going to happen in a couple of years. But they don't care…they make their money and their sheep are happy, believing that their money will keep on growing endlessly.

Comment: Anyway….it's fine with me. If people choose to trust their money to things they don't understand, that's their decision. We'll see who'll be surviving when the market goes down. Pretty big chance it's not the people that put their money into mutual funds. If you want to know more about where my view came from, read "Rich Dad Poor Dad" and "Prophecy" by Robert Kyosaki and "When Money Destroys Nations" by "Philip Haslam".

Comment: And about gold not being an investment; it made me thousands of dollars in the past months. Sounds like a pretty good investment to me.

Comment: @RNobel: Re gold, if you were lucky enough to buy in say 2000 and sell in 2013, you would have made a good profit.  But if you'd bought in 2012 and sold today, you'd have a loss: https://goldprice.org/gold-price-history.html  So how is the variation in gold prices any different from the stock market's ups and downs?  Except that stocks generally pay dividends, while you have to pay to store your gold.

Comment: @jamesqf Gold is not just to be bought or sold, especially not in physical form. You can make lots of money by using derivatives, which I mentioned before; financial products that track the price of gold in which one can invest. Gold and silver are just not very sexy to most investors. But if you know how the derivatives work and that you can make both money when the price goes up as well as down, there's a lot of money to be made. No need to store gold whatsoever.

Comment: As for the risk of losing your money; gold tends to go up in case of economic weakness. When stocks are going down, investors flee to gold and silver. And compared to fiat currencies like the dollar, having no intrinsic value, the chance of gold going to zero is very unlikely. It’s been around thousands of years longer than the stock market. Read ‘when money destroys nations’ to understand how fiat currencies tend to decline to zero almost always. Here's a nice comparison between gold and s&p 500 that will shock most people: http://cnb.cx/2FTmzDv

Comment: The thing is….most people are very good at giving their opinions and advice about money. And somehow we're all conditioned to take this advice for granted. Yet when you do some research you find out that most people have absolutely no idea what they're talking about. We're just copying each other's opinions, which are mostly incorrect or incomplete. And then when someone challenges these opinions and comes up with the facts, people get mad at the messenger. Humans can be so strange. The facts are out in the open. So the choice is: do you believe the opinions or the facts? Easy choice for me

Comment: I know this is more than a year old, but "*under someone else's name*" is what really jumps out at me.  Only bad things can happen with this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To respond to a couple of points up front:

> there are limitations as to when you can rent a property after buying a mortgage (I think). eg: can't rent it out until 6 months have passed

I don't know where you heard that, but that's complete rubbish. Any bank granting you a buy-to-let mortgage (BTL) wants you to be earning rent as soon as possible.

> My mother wants him to put this money into buying a property

In many (if not most) parts of the UK, £20k is not nearly enough. The best BTL mortgage rates kick in if the loan-to-value LTV ratio is below 60%, which means that a £20k deposit will get you a property worth £50k, which is practically impossible these days. You can get mortgages with higher LTVs, but they have higher interest rates.

In any case, as you've mentioned, there are up-front costs (e.g. stamp duty, legal fees, mortgage fees, any costs for getting the property in a state suitable to rent); and you need a contingency fund for periods without tenants, and for repairs.

So to summarise: this is a terrible idea, as £20k is not even close to being enough money to invest in your own buy-to-let property.

---

Investment of any kind is generally a long-term activity, so what are your brother's long term plans?

If he's planning to go to university, he might do better sticking it in a bond (or even a current account with a decent interest rate) for a couple of years, and then spending it on his education.

If he expects to grow the business, maybe he should keep it available in order to invest in that.

Without knowing his intentions, I'd argue that it would be unwise to suggest any particular course of action for his money.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure about the current state of property prices in the UK, so I cannot give you advice on that.

I can give you some advice on alternative ways to spend the 20k.

Like most people, my financial IQ was not very high in and before my twenties. I didn't know how to manage money very well. Everything that came in flew out even faster. It took me another 15 years to understand why financial iq is one of the most important things to have in order to succeed in life, business and investing.

My advice on spending the 20K: keep most of it in your savings account, for now. Re-invest in the business when necessary. Invest the rest in educating yourself and start with your financial IQ. There are numerous ways to do this. I'd start by reading "Rich Dad Poor Dad" by Robert Kyosaki. (and read 'Prophecy' by the same writer to understand why I concluded the first sentence with 'for now').

Do not invest in the stock market, as most stocks, index trackers, funds, etf's are overvalued and there's always a risk of losing your money, even with funds. We're near the top of the economic cycle (see [this chart](http://www.mindfulsharetrader.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Market-Emotional-cycle.jpg) to understand why) and there's a good chance that the stock market will go down somewhere within the coming two years. That doesn't mean that this will happen for sure, but better be prepared for it and don't take the risk of losing your money.

And of course…the majority of users on this site will speak against this advice. If I learned one thing in my life to be important it's to avoid following the majority. If you learn more about life and how this world is run you'll understand why.

All the best and good luck.

Comment: Why on earth would anyone want to downvote this answer? If you do, at least let everyone here see why you disagree with this advice

Comment: I'm well into my 40s and have no idea how you, or anyone else, would define "financial IQ". I would guess it's probably some self-help peddler's latest greatest batch of snake oil. And I'd bet the single way to acquire this "most important things to have" is to buy their books and seminars.

Comment: Judgements, judgements, judgements...before you make any, maybe you should do some research before writing off someone's honest answer and advice. Do some googling, AT LEAST. If you're not open to anyone else's views or advice, what are you doing on this website? The sole purpose of this website is to share advice and opinions. No problem if you don't like to take advice, but stop downvoting someone's advice. Please. Keep this website constructive and helpful.

Comment: And for anyone else reading this. There's different types of intelligence: intellectual intelligence (IQ), emotional intelligence (EQ), social intelligence (SQ), financial intelligence (FQ). Financial IQ defines how smart you are with money, it's as simple as that.

Comment: "_Why on earth would anyone want to downvote this answer?_" I haven't but two possible reasons are **(a)** Your first line has "_current state of property prices in the US_" in response to a question tagged `united-kingdom`, and **(b)** I'm not making a judgement either way as to who may or may not be right, but your anti-stock-market / anti-tracker-funds stance is at odds with (what to me appears to be) a sizeable portion of the users of this site, and so (rightly or wrongly) is likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for your honest answer TripeHound. I'm used to the objectivity and positiveness of stackoverflow. I now see that this stackexchange site is a whole different cookie.

Comment: Downvoted because of your suggestion not to invest in the stock market, period.  Now I might agree that right now is not the best time to invest in stocks, and that for instance parking money in something like a bond fund for a while might be a good idea.  Even so, the person in question is 16: he has plenty of time to weather short-term market swings.  For instance, even if he'd invested at the top of the market in '08, he'd be back even in 5 years, and about 25% ahead today - in addition to whatever dividends were paid in those years.

Comment: @jamesqf: Same answer as to your other comment: past performance is no guarantee for the future. We've had 3 crashes since 2000, each of them 'saved' by the central banks by printing money out of thin air and lowering interest rates. Rates cannot go down a lot further and there's an end to printing money. The growth we saw in the stock market is not based on real growth but on this printed money being 'invested' in the stock market. That's a very dangerous situation to be in